# how to mention/tag users with '@' on a django developed project

Tags: python, django, django-templates, instagram, social-networking

I am trying to implement the "@" feature used on social sites such as twitter to tag or mention users on my django project. Say for example, "@stack" when clicked should go to stack's profile.

How to do that would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 6):

The mention system handled on editor right? Here is [django-markdown-editor](https://github.com/agusmakmun/django-markdown-editor/blob/master/martor/extensions/mention.py) who providing to direct mention user `@[username]` => [@username](http://sitename.to/username)

see also about function [`markdown_find_mentions`](https://github.com/agusmakmun/django-markdown-editor/wiki/Useful-Functions), useful if you need to implement the notification system for user mentioned by another users, something like stackoverflow.

```
def markdown_find_mentions(markdown_text):
    """
    To find the users that mentioned
    on markdown content using `BeautifulShoup`.

    input  : `markdown_text` or markdown content.
    return : `list` of usernames.
    """
    mark = markdownify(markdown_text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(mark, 'html.parser')
    return list(set(
        username.text[1::] for username in
        soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'direct-mention-link'})
    ))
```

and this a simply flow process to do;

1. When create a comment/post/etc, find all users mentioned and create a notification.
2. When edit a commemnt/post/etc, find all new users mentioned and create a notification.

> Makesure the Notification have a sender and receiver.

```
class Notification(TimeStampedModel):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender_n')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='receiver_n')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='n', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    ....
```