# mentioning or tagging users or any models in django

Tags: python, django, mention

Let's say I have a django project of a social network and this site has many users. All the users come from django.contrib.auth.models.User class. Now one user let's say writes a blog and in it, mentions another user with '@' similar to of twitter. So exactly how to do this? What kind of approach should be taken?

And coming away from just user model, rather how to do this with any custom model also? Like if I have a Blog model and each blog has a title, how to mention with that title? And most importantly this mentioning should be an automatic thing. Like If one user's name is "PhantomWarrior", then if one writes "@Phant" and he is still writing, it should automatically predict the username "PhantomWarrior" and give the user option to select that for mentioning. 
Similarly how to do this with the title of a blog?

I found this post: [how to mention/tag users with '@' on a django developed project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930987/how-to-mention-tag-users-with-on-a-django-developed-project) in stackoverflow talking about this thing but the answer kind of did not satisfy what I am wanting.

So how to do this? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @fpaekoaji did you find any solution? I need help with something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways.
In any cases you need add m2m field from blog post to user model.

1. Simplest solution. After any creation or changes in model you need to check content and parse text for all `@NAME` patterns, for example using regexp. After this you need search all founded patterns in user model and add it to m2m field in blog post.
2. This solution used in most cases like you wrote. You need add frontend component, that open autocomplete every time, when you write @ in text boxes. This autocomplete component should be connected to api method, that returns list of users names and IDs, by search pattern. When you select user in autocomplete you need store his ID in some storage on frontend side. When form will be send, you send user IDs with all other form data, and save it in m2m field in blog post.