# How to notify users when other users tagged them on a post - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I'm a student working on a very basic social medial app, The functionality i'd like to implement is that when a user is posting something and mentions another user using "@username", the mentioned user should be notified, I'd like to have a view that shows all of your mentions and the number of them, they should also go away once you have checked the notifications page.

The main question is how to go about notifying the user in the first place, I figured I should have some Notification class implemented and also a helper function that checks for '@username' pattern after every post. I've found some similar posts but they either seem over complicated and poorly explained, to me  [how to mention/tag users with '@' on a django developed project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930987/how-to-mention-tag-users-with-on-a-django-developed-project) or the answer is just not there [How to mention users using @ in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880201/how-to-mention-users-using-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

For real time notifying the tagged user you need to working with web sockets
when the user tags another username you can send request to server(asgi.py) and there you can send notification to tagged user.