# Django Custom Template Filter - How To Mention Users And Categories

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am making a social networking site, and I want to be able to mention users or categories by using the **#** symbol. (Example: **#User #Category #Other Category**). Using a template filter, I want to first find all the # in the string, and then get the word after it. Then I would check in the models for categories:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    category_detail = models.TextField(max_length=1250, default='No information is known on this category.')
```

And if it does not match a category I would check if the word after the # is a user. If It is a category, I want to link it using the `<a>` tag, and if it is a user I also want to link it using the `<a>` tag.

The urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('u/@<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),  # User Profile Link. Link This If After The # The Word Is A User
   path('c/<str:cats>/', views.category_view, name='category-detail'),  # View Category Link. Link This If After The # The Word Is A Category
]
```

**Usage:**
Going back to the example, let's say I have a comment like this:

This is such a great post! #some_user #category #other_category

And in my template I render it like:

```
{{ comment.text|safe|filter_to_parse }}
```

I want the template filter `filter_to_parse` to return:

```
This is such a great post! <a href="/u/@some_user">#some_user</a> <a href="/c/category">#category</a> <a href="/c/other_category">#other_category</a>
```

So how would I make a template filter in Django to do this?

I have found some things that would've helped me do this:

- [How to mention users using @ in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880201/how-to-mention-users-using-in-django)
- https://pypi.org/project/django-mentions/

But the code from these links don't work. Thanks.

**Edit 2:**
Ok so thanks to @flaunder, I have added mark_safe and tried to debug the filter. Here's the working code I have so far:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='mention', is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def mention(value):
    my_list = value.split()
    for i in my_list:
        if i[0] == '@':
            try:
                stng = i[1:]
                user = User.objects.get(username=stng)
                if user:
                    profile_link = user.userprofile.get_absolute_url()
                    i = f"<a href='{profile_link}'>{i}</a>"
                    res = res + i + ' '
                    return mark_safe(res)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return value
        else:
            return value
```

This worked and in the templates it has a link to the user profile, but the rest of the comment is missing. Example: "@da hi!" became "[@da](/u/@da)", with no hi! This is because it returns res, which is the  tag and a space, so I need help returning the rest of the comment too.

The other problem with this code is that if you are mentioning multiple users like @da @user2, then only the first user becomes a url and the rest are just text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is fully untested code, but to get you going:
def mention(original):
listAts = list()

```
 for i in my_list:
    if i[0] == '@':
        try:
          stng = i[1:]
          user = User.objects.get(username = stng)
          if user:
             profile_link = user.userprofile.get_absolute_url()
             i = f"<a href='{profile_link}'>{i}</a>"

        except User.DoesNotExist:
        print("Could not get the data")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the mentioned comment:

```
 @register.filter(name='mention', is_safe=True)
  @stringfilter
  def mention(value):
     res = ""
     my_list = value.split()
     for i in my_list:
        if i[0] == '@':
            try:
              stng = i[1:]
              user = User.objects.get(username = stng)
              if user:
                 profile_link = user.userprofile.get_absolute_url()
                 i = f"<a href='{profile_link}'>{i}</a>"

            except User.DoesNotExist:
            print("Could not get the data")

      res = res + i + ' '
    
   return res
```

Did you load the tags and use the mention filter?

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot for your answer. I have loaded the tag and used the filter correctly, but in the templates after rendering, it just removes the @ and the word. For example if I had "@da hi" it just removes the @da and in the template is shows just "hi". I have edited my answer for more details.

Comment: Did you try to step into the code? what does res hold after the function? Try to remove "safe" from the template tags, it probably filters out the "ahref" part. Try also to return something without html.

Answer (score 0):

correct answer would be:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
@register.filter(name='mention', is_safe=True)
  @stringfilter
  def mention(value):
     res = ""
     my_list = value.split()
     for i in my_list:
        if i[0] == '@':
            try:
              stng = i[1:]
              user = User.objects.get(username = stng)
              if user:
                 profile_link = user.userprofile.get_absolute_url()
                 i = f"<a href='{profile_link}'>{i}</a>"

            except User.DoesNotExist:
            print("Could not get the data")

      res = res + i + ' '
    
   return mark_save(res)
```

[mark_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe): Explicitly mark a string as safe for (HTML) output purposes. The returned object can be used everywhere a string is appropriate.

Comment: I have edited my question with working code. The code works, except it returns just the <a href="/u/@da">@da</a>, without the rest of the comment included.

Comment: The other problem with this code is that if you are mentioning multiple users like "@da @user2", then only the first user becomes a url and the rest are just text.

Comment: yes, but this has nothing to do with the filter not working. You have to rework the function mention.

Comment: To give you an idea: Rework the mention function in a way that it searches for all instances of "@" and for all spaces followed the position of the @'s. Then you have the usernames when doing text[posAt:posSpace] and then you can replace that string with the url you want. Readups: String Slicing in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully functional code, but to get you started:

```
 def mention(value):
     listOfAts = list()
     listOfSpaces = list()
     lastPosOfAt = 0
     while True:
       at = value.find("@", lastPosOfAt+1)
       if at != -1:
         lastPosOfAt = at
         listofAts.append(at)
       else:
         break
```

Then you have a list of all the positions of the "@" in 'value'.