# How can i use tag user using @ in django

Tags: python, django, tags

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to add `tag user system` in creating post using **@**.

I did't find any libraries to implement it in django app.

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to build tagging user with **@**. So when user press @ and press of users(friends) appears.

Same like `stack overflow` while someone add @ then user involved in that post appears.

**What have i tried**

- I saw few answers on `tagging user using @` but they didn't work for me. Like :- [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930987/how-to-mention-tag-users-with-on-a-django-developed-project).
- I also tried `mark_down` to tag immediately ( Like autocomplete ). BUT FAILED. :- [THIS](https://github.com/agusmakmun/django-markdown-editor/wiki/Useful-Functions)
- I tried using `ManyToMany Field` but it would not be like **@**.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='',

    mark = markdownify(markdown_text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(mark, 'html.parser')
    return list(set(
        username.text[1::] for username in
        soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'direct-mention-link'})
```

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Also, the `markdown` didn't work for me

Comment: did you find any solution? I need help with something similar.

Comment: @AryanShandilya, I created my own functionality to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand tagging is done from the frontend and this can be done with the help of js and you need to make these changes in the template.

So you need to trigger an event whenever the user enters @ and the trigger should suggest the list of the user as per your requirement and then he can select the user and that will be tagged in the backend once the user submits.